# How do I debug a stand-alone VBScript script?

Tags: debugging, vbscript

I have a [VBScript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VBScript) script that takes 2 command-line arguments and does some validation.
I need to debug this to see how the program is getting executed.
I was trying to paste this into Excel (using [VBA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_Basic_for_Applications)). However there are some constructs like `Const`, etc. that are not being supported, plus certain validations like taking the command-line arguments are failing.

Hence I would like to know if there is any way to debug this script.
I have Windows XP and Office 2003 installed. I cannot install any other applications on the office computer.

Comment: **Note:** There is also an answer regarding VBScript debugging with Visual Studio, you can find it  [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23210905/1016343).

Answer (score 54, accepted):

Run cscript.exe for full command args, I think

```
cscript //X scriptfile.vbs MyArg1 MyArg2
```

will run the script in a debugger.

Comment: I am getting an error cscript //X test.vbs ...
CScript Error: Initialization of the Windows Script Host failed. (Access is denied.)
must be something to do with priviliges on my computer.

Comment: You need administrative access to run a debugger.

Comment: I get a different problem. I select Visual Studio 2012 as a debugger, then the IDE opens with a solution called "cscript" containing a "cscript" document, but that's all, my script does not appear nowhere.

Comment: I just wanted to add that if you use the Cscript //X <filename> method and no debugger comes up (even though Microsoft Script Debugger is installed), you probably have to add a registry key that selects the debugger. [Source](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/308364)

Save the following code in a reg file and point the path to your debugger. It does not have to be the full path

`Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\{834128A2-51F4-11D0-8F20-00805F2CD064}\LocalServer32]
@="C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Script Debugger\\msscrdbg.exe"`

Comment: This immediately ran my VBS script without giving me a chance to set breakpoints or inspect variables.

Comment: @wil As is, the debugger will only halt the script if there is an error. If you pass the `//D` option on the command line, the script break at the first line, without waiting for an unhandled error.

Answer (score 6):

For posterity, here's **Microsoft's article KB308364** on the subject. This no longer exists on their website, [it is from an archive](https://web.archive.org/web/20150220132115/http://support.microsoft.com/kb/308364).

> *How to debug Windows Script Host, VBScript, and JScript files*
>
> **SUMMARY**
>
> The purpose of this article is to explain how to debug Windows Script
> Host (WSH) scripts, which can be written in any ActiveX script
> language (as long as the proper language engine is installed), but
> which, by default, are written in VBScript and JScript. There are
> certain flags in the registry and, depending on the debugger used,
> certain required procedures to enable debugging.
>
> **MORE INFORMATION**
>
> To debug WSH scripts in Microsoft Visual InterDev, the Microsoft
> Script Debugger, or any other debugger, use the following command-line
> syntax to start the script:
>
> ```
> wscript.exe //d <path to WSH file>
> ```
>
> This code informs the user when a runtime error has occurred and gives the user a choice to debug the application. Also, the //x flag
> can be used, as follows, to throw an immediate exception, which starts
> the debugger immediately after the script starts running:
>
> ```
> wscript.exe //d //x <path to WSH file>
> ```
>
> After a debug condition exists, the following registry key determines which debugger will be used:
>
> ```
> HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\{834128A2-51F4-11D0-8F20-00805F2CD064}\LocalServer32
> ```
>
> The script debugger should be Msscrdbg.exe, and the Visual InterDev
> debugger should be `Mdm.exe`.
>
> If Visual InterDev is the default debugger, make sure that
> just-in-time (JIT) functionality is enabled. To do this, follow these
> steps:
>
> 1. Start Visual InterDev.
> 2. On the Tools menu, click Options.
> 3. Click Debugger, and then ensure that the Just-In-Time options are selected for both the  General and Script categories.
>
> Additionally, if you are trying to debug a .wsf file, make sure that
> the following  registry key is set to 1:
>
> ```
> HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows Script\Settings\JITDebug
> ```
>
> **PROPERTIES**
>
> Article ID: `308364` - Last Review: June 19, 2014 - Revision: 3.0
>
> Keywords: `kbdswmanage2003swept kbinfo KB308364`

Answer (score 5):

This is for future readers. I found that the simplest method for me was to use Visual Studio -> Tools -> External Tools.
More details in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23210905/visual-studio-2013-and-vb-scripts).

Easier to use and good debugging tools.

Answer (score 3):

Click the `mse7.exe` installed along with Office typically at `\Program Files\Microsoft Office\OFFICE11`.

This will open up the debugger, open the file and then run the debugger in the GUI mode.

Answer (score -1):

Export this folder to a backup file and try remove this folder and all the content.

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Script Debugger
```