# vbscript debugger

Tags: vbscript

I have a vbscript that works in development but not the server.

I want to debug this, but I don't want to install visual studio on the server.

What is the most lightweight way to debug this using a debugger?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I debug a stand-alone VBScript script?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2288043/how-do-i-debug-a-stand-alone-vbscript-script)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you're referring to "classic" VBScript, i.e. `.vbs` files, Microsoft has a tool available called [Microsoft Script Debugger](http://www.microsoft.com/en-ca/download/details.aspx?id=22185) that functions more or less like a Visual Studio debugging session. It's probably your most lightweight option short of adding debug statements to the code.

Comment: This is pretty win for anyone debugging classic asp as well

Comment: @RaulLuna: Doesn't work for me in XP either. Can open the `.vbs` file with the program, but the button to run is not activated. The open dialog doesn't even have the option to filter for `.vbs` files.

Comment: The debugger link doesn't work anymore. "*We're sorry, this download is no longer available.*"

Answer (score 5):

[VBSEdit](http://vbsedit.com/) is great.

The free version does have an annoying timer but it's $59. It does use Microsoft Script Debugger.

Answer (score 0):

You can use either Microsoft's default debugger or [vbsedit](https://htpps://www.vbsedit.com). Vbsedit is a good IDE for VBS, HTA and HTML. And it includes a debugger.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).