# The breakpoint will not currently be hit. no symbols have been loaded for this document. VBScript VS2012

Tags: visual-studio-2012, vbscript

I am maintaining a software developed with **simple ASP (asp) + VBScript**. When I try to debug I get the following message:

> "The breakpoint will not currently be hit. No symbols have been loaded
>   for this document."

The strange thing is that in the **same project** I can debug an **aspx file**.

So my question is. Can I debug with VBScript?

Thank you all.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Visual Studio 2013 and VB Scripts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23210905/visual-studio-2013-and-vb-scripts)