# Visual Studio JIT debugger failed to debug VBS popping out the error: An unhandled exception("Script breakpoint") occurred in cscript.exe

Tags: visual-studio, vbscript

I setup VS debugger config with the method in this link:
[Can you debug VBScript in Visual Studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23210905/can-you-debug-vbscript-in-visual-studio).

It works well for some of my peers, they can debug VBS successfully like setting breakpoint, viewing locals.
But when it comes to my laptop, VS pops out the error like:

[image: VS error]

based on the messages, I've checked the debugger config that all kinds have been checked as below:

[image: VS debugging config]

I even tried to reinstall my VS, but it pops the same error.

My VS version is: VS Professional 2019.

Windows version: Windows 10 Enterprise x64 operating system.

so I suspect there might be something wrong with ../system32/cscript.exe or ../system32/vsjitdebugger.exe

Anyone knows how I can handle this error and debug VBS successfully?

---

### Update 1:

the simple vbs i was trying to debug is like this:

```
dim a 
a=1 
msgbox(a)
```

---

Comment: Did you try option suggested by the error message?

Comment: Yes, I did. the debugging options were actually all checked.